# Change language of texts in Previewer in DevEco

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, harmonyos, deveco-studio

How do we change the language of the texts in the previewer ? Its Chinese for me at present and if I try to change it by **Preview -> Language -> Select Language (eng_US)** then I find a timeout error each time. PLease help me here.

Error Code after i change language：

[image]

Comment: hi@rohangupta8756, could you pls provide the IDE version, project type, and log? Thanks

Comment: @shirley Java 11, Just a beginner - so a random project , There isn't an issue with the code. It is an issue with the previewer . I want to change the language to english but am not able to do so !

Comment: hi@rohangupta8756, Could you pls provide the full error log? In addition, the HarmonyOS does not support the Java 11 project by now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks that was resolved when I reinstalled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just language, what you did should fix it. Please check to see if the previewer is up-to-date:

[image]

Also, there are some previews that are not supported, please check out Previewer's details: https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/previewer-0000001054328973

Previewer FAQ: https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/faq-previewer-operating-0000001056617760

If the error still exists, please share the error log for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just hardcode the text and ignore the warnings
Eg:
In this line -> ohos:text="**$string:entry_MainAbility**"
Change the content between the "" into whatever you like

Say like  ohos:text="Hello Rohan"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).